# Typescript type A is not assignable to type A (same type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having an issue where Typescript tells me that type A is not assignable to type A, but they're exactly the same:

Here is a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCBCArqqgPbICSaGOqiZ8A3gFDzwEDOGAXPFMgJ4BuFvDAdSAW3LAe7VDBQBzYazgAHCPx4AKCSHbsoikLPlKAlPAC8APngA3EomBMAvkyYhkBCfAAqMHzs0KQwADJ8iuyMIgBiAErW8ADkmDDJADQiAKIAcknJXpluHiAAHmokMKii0AbwAKqcMADKGPaIuDGsagQARhCdvOz8yGDwnKhNGGEkYFAQINoc3LwCGfAQcwsm-oHIwVChEchR5jwACjAkEoicADx8-HbMrKwrMAB0W-OLST87FTwdzuTwVKo1FDoLA4fBEUjIAASfGAixglGh2C6r1ENwkKNyUD0pgUpyBAAsUYt7n4kgRkABrZAkADuyBs2ih1DAtDIPEIxDIGO5vOQG3sCwIuz85wcTmA8AAPvArjc7iB7o5nDYSmDKtV4KBsAQIDVIFB6gBZPq0ADCeJRyOQqIwSAkGhAejQ0QFCKdLvRVBh2JEvQGQzADudhL0BUms1+IGSwlDCgl6DYzTaMA6uB401a7U6CCs8GQIBZjSzRdw2nMKdYFtG40pzupASCISqJyiHK5gR5dGQ-PhQqDNCH4sl0v2h2OkXYstVtweWuALxErFQ5Lunw+2dzIE+kwLCZ2nPHg7Ie+aU4gUvrm-gAHpn293x-P1-vz+PwA9ACAKfV9f1A98AEEYEUHwvBqEhMHgVB+DUBBkg7A4u3CBdkiQaJmRqC12EQRRkCgAYEFIeA1FgIkQGheB4MQ5DUPQudu2wp9+wna91E0bQAAMAHkGQ2dgSCQGoWUQCAIHgPoEAAEgYLir2QT4xDkG5pFcfjHyfOBUAIGBkCQS9RU+Xj+G0ZISAZZJH1YEEgA):

```ts
declare interface ButtonInteraction {
  user: any;
  customId: string;
  reply: (message: string) => void
}

enum TranslatorLangs {
  FR = 'fr',
  EN = 'en',
}

export class UserService {
  public async setUserLocale(user: any, locale: TranslatorLangs): Promise<any> {
    user.locale = locale;
  }
}

export interface ButtonHandlerInterface {
  commandName: string;
  handle<T = unknown>(interaction: ButtonInteraction, value: T): void | Promise<void>
}

export default class MbtiCommandHandler implements ButtonHandlerInterface {
  public commandName = 'setLocale';

  private userService: UserService = new UserService();

  async handle<TranslatorLangs>(interaction: ButtonInteraction, value: TranslatorLangs): Promise<void> {
    this.userService.setUserLocale(interaction.user, value);
    //                                               ^^^^^
    //                         Argument of type 'TranslatorLangs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TranslatorLangs'
    interaction.reply(`Ok, so it will be ${interaction.customId}`);

    return interaction.reply('ok');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not actually the same thing, the name "TranslatorLangs" is being used to mean two different things. First, it's an enum. Second, it's a name for the generic parameter than handle accepts. To rename it so i can refer to them separately, let's change the handle function to:

```
async handle<T>(interaction: ButtonInteraction, value: T): Promise<void>
```

This line is saying that `handle` is a generic function. "T" is a placeholder for whatever type they decide to call it with. They might decide that T is TranslatorLangs, but they could also pass in anything else, such as a boolean. So when you try to pass that boolean into setUserLocale, you get an error.

I think what you're trying to do is make `ButtonHandlerInterface` itself be generic, as in:

```
export interface ButtonHandlerInterface<T = unknown> {
  commandName: string;
  handle(interaction: ButtonInteraction, value: T): void | Promise<void>
}
```

You'll then use it like this:

```
export default class MbtiCommandHandler implements ButtonHandlerInterface<TranslatorLangs> {
   // ...
  async handle(interaction: ButtonInteraction, value: TranslatorLangs): Promise<void> {
  // ...
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCBCArqqgPbICSaGOqiZ8A3gFDzwEDOGAXPFMgJ4BuFvDAdSAW3LAe7VDBQBzYazgAHCPx4AKCSHbsoikLPlKAlPAC8APngA3EomBMAvkyYhkBCfAAqMHzs0KQwADJ8iuyMIgBiAErW8ADkmDDJADQiAKIAcknJXpluHiAAHmokMKii0AbwAKqcMADKGPaIuDGsagQARhCdvOz8yGDwnKhNGGEkYFAQINoc3LwCGfAQcwsm-oHIwVChEchR5jwACjAkEoicADx8-HbMrKwrMAB0W-OLST87FTwdzuTwVKo1FDoLA4fBEUjIAASfGAixglGh2Fw9z8SQIyAA1sgSAB3ZAvERgG4SFG5KB6UwKU5AgAWKMW2ih1DAtDIPEIxDIGO5vOQG3sCwIuz85wcTmA8AAPvArjc7iB7o5nDYSuVKtV4KBsAQIDVIFB6gBZPq0ADC1JRyOQqIwSAkGhAejQ0QFCKdLvRVBh2ICQRCVROUQpPX6g3GVIkNOddL0BUms1%20IGSwhEagUEvQbGabRgHVwPGmrXanQQVngyBAJMaxeruG05hzrAto3GbOdHK5gR5dGQ-PhQqDNBH4sl0v2h2OkXYstVtweWuA0beqBZd0%20HxLZZAn0mlYzO05k%20HZH3zRnEClHZErEHU5v6k02gABgB5AkbdgSCQGoSUQCAIHgPoEAAEgYV9r2QT4xDkG5pFcL8n2feA4FQAgYGQJAr1FT4P34bRkhIAlkifVgQSAA)

Comment: Oh thank you, now I get the error. It's because I gave the generic the same name.